# Does GC.SuppressFinalize is useless if there is no Finalizer in the class?

Tags: c#

While using the Dispose pattern in a Class, I see that there is not Finalizer present but still GC.SuppressFinalize() being used in the Dispose method.

Is this call useless or is there a Finalizer implicitly provided by the runtime in a class?

Comment: It's useless if there's no finalizer.

Comment: Well, the reason it's there in the full Dispose pattern is in case a child class adds a finalizer. The official advice on the full Dispose pattern is changing however: it's preferred that you never write a finalizer, and assume that any derived classes won't either. If you need to handle unmanaged resources, use a `SafeHandle`, which avoids some very non-obvious pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Dispose pattern are you seeing? The one for `sealed` classes or the one for classes designed for inheritance?

For the latter, there's no real way to know whether a derived class will have a finalizer and so the base class implementing `Dispose` should still have the call to `SuppressFinalize`.